# postgres cast json vs. to_json function (why different output)

Tags: json, postgresql, casting, jsonb

I have a Postgres table like:

```
CREATE table json_str(
    foo int,
    js text
);
insert into json_str(foo, js) values (1, '{ "key": "value", "foo": 1}');
```

and want to cast the column `js` of type `text` to JSON.
Why is the output of `cast` different from `to_json`?

Ideally, I can fit the type change into an alter table statement. However, a simple cast is not accepted and I am forced to use to_json (which returns doubly quoted non-plain JSON. Is there a way to get the standard (direct) JSON layout for an alter table statement?

```
select * from json_str;
-- { "key": "value", "foo": 1}
select cast(js as jsonb) from json_str;
--- {"foo": 1, "key": "value"}
select to_json(js) from json_str;
-- "{ \"key\": \"value\", \"foo\": 1}"

alter table json_str alter column js  type jsonb using to_jsonb(js);
select * from json_str;
-- "{ \"key\": \"value\", \"foo\": 1}"
```

Comment: It looks like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270178/to-json-vs-json-in-postgres is the reason (to_json is a conversion and not casting function).

Comment: Because `to_json()`  is producing a `JSON` string not a `json` type.

Comment: What do you mean by "*a simple cast is not accepted*"?

Comment: Without the using clause

Answer (score 0):

This is the working alter table statement:

```
alter table json_str alter column js  type jsonb using js::jsonb;
```